# How can I use HttpRequestMessage.CreateResponse<HttpError>() in ASP.NET 5

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core

I have empty Web API project as well as full MVC project created using VS2015. I notice `HttpRequestMessage` is in `System.Net.Http`, thats fine but not for the `CreateResponse` below:

This code is from my exception logger middleware that also return formatted json from previous Web API 2.

```
var resp = request.CreateResponse<HttpError>(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, new HttpError("Internal Server Error. Reference: " + guid), config);
```

I am struggling to find out the `CreateResponse` extension method that supposedly available in `System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessageExtensions` as well as `HttpError` class. Both previously in  `Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core` package.

After looking on ASP.NET 5 code, I believe it is only available in [`Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.WebApiCompatShim`](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/tree/6.0.0-beta6/src/Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.WebApiCompatShim). However it does not included in MVC sample project.

**Questions:**

What is `WebApiCompatShim` package and can I safely use it in the project?

What is the right way to `CreateResponse` from `HttpRequestMessage`?

**Update**

[This WebApiCompatShimWebSite](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/6.0.0-beta8/test/WebSites/WebApiCompatShimWebSite/readme.md) shows that `WebApiCompatShim` is

> to get Web API 2.* like behavior

So seems just for compatibility purpose. I have to restructure the code. Now I discover the MVC doesn't have any message handlers feature and seems custom middleware is the way to go.

Answer (score 5):

If you add the NuGet Package `Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core`, you will get the extensions you are looking for.

reference: https://www.nuget.org/packages/microsoft.aspnet.webapi.core/

Comment: But I believe this package is not for ASP.NET 5

Answer (score 3):

That is an extension method of `HttpRequestMessage` class.
You must reference to the below DLL which is included in Nuget Package [Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core](https://www.nuget.org/packages/microsoft.aspnet.webapi.core/):

```
Nuget\packages\Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core.5.2.3\lib\net45\System.Web.Http.dll
```

This time you then can see `CreateResponse` method:

```
var response = request.CreateResponse(...)
```

Answer (score 2):

According to:

https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/tutorials/first-web-api.html

You can achieve similar functionality by creating a new instance of `ObjectResult` (the status code can later be changed by setting the `StatusCode` property).