# No overload for method 'CreateResponse' takes 2 arguments after upgrading Web API

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

ASP.NET / Mono MVC 4 application was upgraded to .NET 4.6 and new Web API

In API controllers APIController base class was changed to Controller base class.

After that code

```
    public class APIBase : Controller
    {
        protected HttpResponseMessage CreateSchedule(int[] selected, char dokument, string subtype)
        {
...
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, new { Dokumnr = kanne });

        }
```

throws compile error

```
No overload for method 'CreateResponse' takes 2 arguments
```

How to fix this ?

Comment: Please see [How can I use HttpRequestMessage.CreateResponse<HttpError>() in ASP.NET 5](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33516001/how-can-i-use-httprequestmessage-createresponsehttperror-in-asp-net-5)

Comment: Answers to this recommend to install `Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core' package. Latest of this package (v5.2.3) is installed but problem persists. Code can re-factored if required. Question asks for best practice to fix  this issue.